# color conversion CMYK - RGB - Lab with WCS by using a ICC Profile

Tags: c#, dll, colors, type-conversion, color-profile

Since last week I try to use the Windows Color System for my color conversion. By the conversion from CMYK to RGB i get the correct values:

```
    // Example CMYK - VALUES with 0
    float[] cmykValues = new float[4];
    cmykValues[0] = 0f / 255f;
    cmykValues[1] = 0f / 255f;
    cmykValues[2] = 0f / 255f;
    cmykValues[3] = 0f / 255f;

    System.Windows.Media.Color color = Color.FromValues(cmykValues, new Uri(@"ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc"));
    System.Drawing.Color rgbColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

When I try to convert the RGB Values to Lab Values, then I get a incorrect Lab - Result:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RGBColor
{
    public ushort red;
    public ushort green;
    public ushort blue;
    public ushort pad;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LABColor
{
    public ushort L;
    public ushort a;
    public ushort b;
    public ushort pad;
};

 StringBuilder profileName = new StringBuilder(256);
 uint size = (uint)profileName.Capacity * 2;
 success = GetStandardColorSpaceProfile(0, LogicalColorSpace.sRGB, profileName, ref size);

 ProfileFilename sRGBFilename = new ProfileFilename(profileName.ToString());
 IntPtr hSRGBProfile = OpenColorProfile(sRGBFilename, ProfileRead, FileShare.Read, CreateDisposition.OpenExisting);

 ProfileFilename isoCoatedFilename = new ProfileFilename(@"ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc");
 IntPtr hIsoCoatedProfile = OpenColorProfile(isoCoatedFilename, ProfileRead, FileShare.Read, CreateDisposition.OpenExisting);

 IntPtr[] profiles = new IntPtr[] { hSRGBProfile, hIsoCoatedProfile };
 uint[] intents = new uint[] { IntentPerceptual };
 IntPtr transform = CreateMultiProfileTransform(profiles, 2, intents, 1, ColorTransformMode.BestMode, IndexDontCare);

 RGBColor[] rgbColors = new RGBColor[1];
 rgbColors[0] = new RGBColor();
 LABColor[] labColors = new LABColor[1];
 labColors[0] = new LABColor();

 rgbColors[0].red    = Convert.ToUInt16(rgbColor.R * 257);
 rgbColors[0].green  = Convert.ToUInt16(rgbColor.G * 257);
 rgbColors[0].blue   = Convert.ToUInt16(rgbColor.B * 257);

 success = TranslateColors(transform, rgbColors, 1, ColorType.RGB, labColors, ColorType.Lab);

 double colorL = Convert.ToDouble(labColors[0].L) / 65535;
 double colorA = Convert.ToDouble(labColors[0].a) / 65535;
 double colorB = Convert.ToDouble(labColors[0].b) / 65535;
```

When I convert the CMYK Value (0;0;0;0) to RGB (= 254:254;254) and the RGB Value to Lab I get the following values:

```
L = 0.0039978637360036373
a = 0.002777141984552145
b = 0.0030670634005218744
```

But the L-Value should be about 100%

Comment: There's just not enough information here to solve the problem. What does `TranslateColors` look like? What about `GetStandardColorSpaceProfile`? You'd be much better off asking a generic question about converting CMYK to LAB.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't think that the color profile `ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc` works for Lab colors. It probably only supports CMYK to RGB (and vice versa) conversions. You'll probably need a specific profile for Lab colors.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The TranslateColors function translates an array of colors from the source color space to the destination color space as defined by a color transform. The GetStandardColorSpaceProfile function retrieves the color profile registered for the specified standard color space.

Comment: @Codo I have try it with different profiles. And I get always different values. Therefore I think the profiles support Lab colors. I think, that the DLL would return a error or a static 0 value. Isn't it so? Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I think you don't need to use a print profile (`CMYK`) when converting from color monitor's (`RGB`) to a device independent color model (`Lab`).

[RGB -> XYZ -> Lab](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Math.html) or [this](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH)